# Ignore onclick on specific div element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<pre>
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
<script src="Puzzle.js"></script>
<button id="button1" onclick="numbersDisplay();">Start New Game</button>
<div id="tableDiv" >
</div>
</pre>
```

What I want to do is just to ignore onclicks on specific div elements with an if else statements.

The if else statements are working properly but I don't know how to ignore clicks...

All if else if is just to prevent the user clicks in a div elements, i just want a some div's to have a possible moves, this is the slidding puzzle what i have doing

```js
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {

    output += '<div id="' + i + j + '" onclick="tableMove(this,\'' + table[i][j] + '\')">' + table[i][j] + '</div>';
  }
}
document.getElementById('tableDiv').innerHTML = output;

var search = document.querySelector('div').childNodes;
var array = [].slice.call(search);

for (var c in array) {

  elements = array[c];

  if (elements.textContent === '0') {
    zero = elements.id;
    document.getElementById(zero).innerHTML = '';

    i1 = zero[0];
    j1 = zero[1];

    posZero = table[i1][j1];
  }
}
}

function tableMove(num, val) {

  i2 = num.id[0];
  j2 = num.id[1];

  table[i1][j1] = table[i2][j2];
  table[i2][j2] = posZero;


  if (i1 !== i2 && j1 !== j2) {
    document.getElementById(num.id).removeEventListener("click", tableMove);//<---this dont work in all if else if statements

      else if((i1=Number(i1)+1) === i2 && j1 === j2 ){
    document.getElementById(num.id).removeAttribute("onclick");

}
else if((i1=Number(i1)-1) === i2 && j1 === j2){
    document.getElementById(num.id).removeAttribute("onclick");

}
else if((j1 = Number(j1)+1) === j2 && i1 === i2){
    document.getElementById(num.id).removeAttribute("onclick");

}

else if((j1 = Number(j1)-1) === j2 && i1 === i2){
    document.getElementById(num.id).removeAttribute("onclick");

}

return numbersDisplay();
```

}

Comment: Paste the code here, you don't need to upload a screenshot of the code. It's even better if you  provide a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Aminadav - and even even better if he provides a stacksnippet

Comment: Is this what do you mean?

Comment: Almost. Please click the `<>` and add relevant HTML and complete running code

Comment: I think its right now :D

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example with a blue div similar with your scenario.

When the div is clicked, it will execute the JS and call event StopPropagation.

```js
document.querySelector('.div').addEventListener(
 "click",
  function(e){
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = "Do your if/else code here!";
    e.stopPropagation();
 },
 true
)
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
</div>

<p>
Click on blue div, it will call the JS
</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean with that code that i have to remove the onclick that i have put in divs in this line:    output += '<div id="' + i + j + '" onclick="tableMove(this,\'' + table[i][j] + '\')">' + table[i][j] + '</div>';
  }

Answer (score 0):

just use a specific class for your unclickable divs? for example

```
.unclickable {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: but the divs gonna be unclickable just in the onclick user, after a rigth click they come clickable again